# Query data in an specified interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query a **timesheet** where time span (cycle) is 21 to 20, thus today (10/30/2014) is November.

So, 10/14/2014 is October.

2014-09-21 and 2014-10-20 is one time span
2014-10-21 and 2014-11-20 is one time span

The table is simply storing the date for the timesheet:

```
id date hours
```

So, I can specifically say:

```
SELECT * FROM rapoarte WHERE DATE(ziua) BETWEEN "2014-09-21" AND "2014-10-20"
```

But I can't figure out how to:

- How can I query through this interval for say 1 year (or more)
- How can I query for this month?

dynamically

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, there are 31 days in October so even if the day switches at 9pm it would still be October tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to do date arithmetic.  So, for October, you would use:

```
SELECT *
FROM rapoarte
WHERE month(DATE(ziua) - interval 20 day + interval 1 month) = 10
```

The idea is to subtract 20 days and add a month.  This seems to be the logic for the reporting month.

You can add this as a field:

```
SELECT *,
       date_format(month(DATE(ziua) - interval 20 day + interval 1 month), '%Y-%m') as ReportingMonth
FROM rapoarte
WHERE month(DATE(ziua) - interval 20 day + interval 1 month) = 10
```

EDIT:

If you want data for this reporting month:

```
WHERE month(DATE(ziua) - interval 20 day + interval 1 month) = month(DATE(now()) - interval 20 day + interval 1 month) and
      year(DATE(ziua) - interval 20 day + interval 1 month) = year(DATE(now()) - interval 20 day + interval 1 month)
```

Comment: Awesome. How would I retrieve the "11" based on todays date?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would want:  month(DATE(now()) - interval 20 day + interval 1 month)

Comment: Yes, you do, however doing the above gives me results from October as well. Today is November (2014-10-21 - 2014-11-20) so it should only give me those rows.

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to determine in one of the query as well as which month it is?